# Firebug not showing any scripts

Tags: firebug

I have ton of scripts on the page and they are not showing in Firebug Script tab.
I get first error: Failed to load source for: /a/j/milonic/milonic_src.js
and that is all I see. I don't have control over this line. Many scripts are working on the page, nothing shows up. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the js file in an another browser tab :
http://yourdomain/a/j/milonic/milonic_src.js

Can you open it?

Comment: But it seems it isn't there . Is it possible, that you used a wrong include path ?  If you try to open Firebug net tab, what you can see there at this js file? Did you try to copy the path from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Google Chrome browser; right click and then 'inspect element'.